# Unable to save excel file using VBScript

Tags: java, excel, vbscript

I'm aware that there are similar situations as mentioned in the title. However, I've spent roughly 30 hours trying to apply as many solutions that were presented by google.

To give some context of my goal, I'm using Java to read an excel file and change certain fields, which then a macro must be executed and the results must be compared to a file to see verify if the calculator is working correctly.

In order to execute this macro through code, I've created a VB script that executes the macro, but the problem is that it keeps complaining that it cannot save the file and that it'd have to save to a temporary excel file such as "8823V828.xlsm". This is a problem because this process has to be automated and the program wouldn't even be able to determine the name of the temp file to verify the results.

If you have a better solution, I'd gladly appreciate the insight.

This is what I've tried so far:

1. Creating a VB Script with the many combinations online (I've tried DisplayAlerts = False, Visible = Flase)

   ```
   Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   Set Wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/339743866/Projects/cob_penguin_test/src/main/resources/outputrtc_calc.xlsm")
   xlApp.Run "CalculatePayments"
   Wb.Save
   Wb.Close
   xlApp.Application.Quit
   ```
2. Creating a save macro that supposedly does not prompt and save the excel file.

   ```
   Sub AutoCloseAndSave()
     If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then
       ThisWorkbook.Save
     End If
   End Sub
   ```

   The VBScript would be

   ```
   Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   Set Wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/339743866/Projects/cob_penguin_test/src/main/resources/outputrtc_calc.xlsm")
   xlApp.Run "CalculatePayments"
   xlApp.Run "AutoCloseAndSave"
   xlApp.Application.Quit
   ```
3. I've enabled the sharing wizard and indexing on the folder
4. I've checked the permissions of the folder and file to see that full permissions have been granted
5. Tried using Wb.SaveAs

Comment: Just something you might try: In the *CloseAndSave* procedure replace `ThisWorkbook` with `Wb` which you can pass as an argument.

Comment: How would I pass the Wb from VBScript to the macro?

Comment: Is the java code closing connection to the excel file after changing values?

Comment: I'm not familiar with VBScript or Java but presume that passing the object variable should be possible at this juncture:- `Set Wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/339743866/Projects/cob_penguin_test/src/main/resources/outputrtc_calc.xlsm"): App.Run "AutoCloseAndSave"`. Else, if identifying the file to be saved or its location is the problem, you might find another way to do it.

Comment: Turns out the problem was because I was only closing the FileInputStream, but not the FileOutputStream...... @Flakes

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.